# Scapy fails to filter certain packets

Tags: python, filter, port, scapy

I have got a simple sniff function set up with scapy which forwards the packet to a handshake function (I have a webserver set up on **port 102**. However some weird errors have come by, then I decided to print pkt.show(), what I discovered was that some packages DID come through the filter somehow.

My sniff function:

```
a=sniff(filter="port 102", count=10, prn=handshake)
```

This packet manages to come through:

```
###[ Ethernet ]###
  dst       = 84:8f:69:f5:fe:ac
  src       = b8:27:eb:92:a3:3b
  type      = 0x800
###[ IP ]###
     version   = 4L
     ihl       = 5L
     tos       = 0x0
     len       = 44
     id        = 1
     flags     =
     frag      = 0L
     ttl       = 64
     proto     = tcp
     chksum    = 0xe6c6
     src       = 192.168.137.178
     dst       = 192.168.137.1
     \options   \
###[ TCP ]###
        sport     = iso_tsap
        dport     = 2426
        seq       = 605952828
        ack       = 605952829
        dataofs   = 6L
        reserved  = 0L
        flags     = SA
        window    = 8192
        chksum    = 0x5b7c
        urgptr    = 0
        options   = [('MSS', 1460)]
```

As you can see the destination port is 2426, which is definetely not **port 102**.

Have I done something dumb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source port in the enclosed packet is [`iso_tsap` which is 102](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers). If you want to filter by the destination port try the filter `"dst port 102"`. If you need something a bit more sophisticated, [here](http://biot.com/capstats/bpf.html) is the syntax of *BPF*, which is used by *scapy*.